# How to check if the API return nothing with Alamofire?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, alamofire, swift5

I am using Alamofire to make an API request to insert user data to my database, if the user email is exist, the response will return

```
[Response]:
    [Status Code]: 200
    [Headers]:
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Length: 27
        Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
        Date: Thu, 22 Apr 2021 06:39:05 GMT
        Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
        Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
    [Body]:
        Email address already exist
[Network Duration]: 0.013917088508605957s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s
[Result]: success(Optional(27 bytes))
```

[image: When user email is exist]
and if user email is not exist, it will insert data to the database, and return nothing like this
[image](literally nothing, there's no character or whatsoever, just a blank page if I open the api in the web browser)

And here is the response

```
[Response]:
    [Status Code]: 200
    [Headers]:
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Length: 0
        Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
        Date: Thu, 22 Apr 2021 06:54:43 GMT
        Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
        Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
    [Body]: None
[Network Duration]: 0.8882529735565186s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s
[Result]: success(nil)
```

Now I want to make a validation to check if user email is exist or not by checking the response body. if the response body is Email address already exist, it will display an error alert. and if response body is None, it will display a successful alert. My question is, how do I check if the response body is None? here is validation code

```
let parameters = ["USERNAME": "\(USERNAME)", "EMAIL": "\(EMAIL)", "FULL_NAME": "\(FULL_NAME)", "NO_TELEPON": "\(NO_TELEPON)", "PASSWORD": "\(PASSWORD)", "USER_TOKEN": "\(USER_TOKEN)"]

AF.request("http://172.16.5.56:8081/User/InsertNewUser", parameters: parameters).response{ response in
    debugPrint(response)
    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
        print(utf8Text)
        postResponse = utf8Text
        if postResponse == "Email address already exist" {
            self.haptics.notificationOccurred(.error)
            self.activeAlert = .first
            self.showAlert = true
        }else if postResponse == "None"{ // This is not working
            self.haptics.notificationOccurred(.success)
            self.activeAlert = .second
            self.showAlert = true
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What about simply `postResponse.isEmpty` instead of `postResponse == "None"`? The response is literally `""` so why compare with `"None"`?

Comment: I've tried that too, but still doesn't work

Comment: what does `print(utf8Text)` output then? Probably `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` is `nil`

Comment: if the user email is exists it will print `Email address already exist`, but if not, it print nothing. I've tried `if utf8Text == nil` too, but it's the same.

Comment: check if `response.data` is `nil`. Maybe that's why it doesn't go inside the condition. Besides why don't you base the success on status code like `200` instead of string comparison?

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at the Result value instead?

Comment: I think you have to return different status codes from the server when email exists and when not. Then you will be able to check the status code in the response.

Comment: yes, the problem is the status code is the same `200`, so I can't check on that. And How do I get the result value? @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for [Alamofire response validation/handling](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-validation), it is not a framework I use myself so it's better if you do the research than me guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response (as you shared) in fail-type case is:

```
[Response]:
    [Status Code]: 200
    [Headers]:
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Length: 0
        Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
        Date: Thu, 22 Apr 2021 06:54:43 GMT
        Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
        Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
    [Body]: None
[Network Duration]: 0.8882529735565186s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s
[Result]: success(nil)
```

Shows `[Result]: success(nil)` which means the `response.data` is literally `nil`.

I propose the following solution:

```
Alamofire
    .request("http://172.16.5.56:8081/User/InsertNewUser")
    .response { (response) in
        if let data = response.data,
           let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            if string == "Email address already exist" {
                self.haptics.notificationOccurred(.error)
                self.activeAlert = .first
                self.showAlert = true
            }
            //else if ... {
            //handle other cases
            //}
        } else { 
            self.haptics.notificationOccurred(.success)
            self.activeAlert = .second
            self.showAlert = true
        }
    }
```

---

NOTE: I would advise against direct string comparisons unless unavoidable.
Atleast agree on a common response template and ensure the responses are not prone to typos or silly mistakes.

Comment: Yes! this absolutely answers to my question. Thanks for the help and sharing your advice with me!

Answer (score 1):

@staticVoidMan has already provided a solution for your current backend setup. However, if you update your backend to return more appropriate responses, Alamofire can do a lot more for you automatically.

In short, you need to make your backend behave in a standard fashion following JSON API best practices. These include:

- In the failure case, return a failure status code (probably 403), and a JSON payload describing the error.
- In the success case, you could return a 201, which indicates the new user has been created, in which case you should include the new user object JSON in the response, or a 204, which is the proper status code for an empty response.

In these cases you can define proper `Decodable` payloads which Alamofire can parse for you, as well as a proper value for the empty responses, and Alamofire will ensure it's returned in the 204 case.